# How to check whether the file exists before making it executable in CMake

Tags: git, cmake, project, clion

I got a CLion project. Inside it, I have several files (e.g. **Task1.cpp**, **Task2.cpp**). I store them in GitHub in one repository but in different branches (**Task1** and **Task2** respectively). So when I checkout for another branch on my laptop there's only one left locally. I need to modify CMakeLists.txt so I can build my project without editing it every time I switch my branch. I tried to write it like that:

```
if(EXISTS Task1.cpp)
  add_executable(Task1 Task1.cpp)
endif()

if(EXISTS Task2.cpp)
  add_executable(Task2 Task2.cpp)
endif()
```

But it seems that CLion doesn't see (or probably doesn't execute) line `add_executable(Task1 Task1.cpp)` in case of being in branch Task1.

Comment: Maybe it is better to create a different CMakeLists.txt for each branch and add them to your git repo. It will be easier to follow the changes you add to each of your branches.

Comment: It seems to me that you have two different projects. I would recommend that you have two different repositories instead, one for each project.

Comment: @luizinho Then what to do when I'd like to merge these two branches? Rewrite **CMakeLists.txt**?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually no. Just I simplified the structure of this example for this question. But I assure you I need it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Despite answering below, I generally agree with the suggestions here for reorganizing your project or CMake files to avoid this `EXISTS` check altogether. If your project has *many* checks like this, I think making a **different** CMake file for each branch might be the best approach.

Comment: @squareskittles hmm. I don't it will work because as I said before these branches have to be different due to the way me and my team are developing this project. But it's a good suggestion and we will think of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#condition-syntax), the file `EXISTS` check is only well-defined for **full** paths:

> ```
> if(EXISTS path-to-file-or-directory)
> ```
>
> True if the named file or directory exists. Behavior is well-defined only for full paths. Resolves symbolic links, i.e. if the named file or directory is a symbolic link, returns true if the target of the symbolic link exists.

Try using the complete path to these files (which is a safer approach, regardless). If these sources are in the same directory as your current CMake file, you can use [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html):

```
if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Task1.cpp)
  add_executable(Task1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Task1.cpp)
endif()

if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Task2.cpp)
  add_executable(Task2 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Task2.cpp)
endif()
```

Comment: But I guess in **add_executable** we don't need full path as in auto-generated *CMakeLists.txt* it's specified just `Task1.cpp` (and it works xd)

Comment: @МаркТюков Yes, relative paths do work in commands such as `add_executable()` and `add_library()`. But, in other commands, relative paths do not work as expected all the time. So, as a general rule, it is easier for me to *always* try to use full paths.

Comment: Could you explain one more thing? I wrote exactly as you did. And it helps. Until I checkout to another branch. When I do that, CLion tells me that he can't find appropriate file. If I remove the block **if** for the appropriate file in CMakeLists and paste it back then it's ok. But it's strange to do that each time I switch my branh

Comment: @МаркТюков So CLion gives a CMake error when you *build* after switching branches? In general, CMake operates based on *caching*. So if the CMake files themselves have not changed, it may not recognize that the source files it references have changed. Only after you make a change to one of your CMake files will CMake recognize that the buildsystem should be *updated* and CMake will re-run to update its cache.